# What does MV_STORE = false mean when connecting to H2 database?

Tags: java, h2

I am working on an Embedded database w/ a GUI to communicate with it.

I am curious what the `MV_STORE = false` means in my URL?

```java
public DBconnect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:h2:~/Database;MV_STORE=false", "admin", "Fitness1");
    }
```

Comment: https://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#storageEngine

Comment: Good question. But please use proper English when posting here: “I am” or “I’m”, not “im”. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room. I edited your text this time.

Answer (score 3):

## Storage engine

[H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) has offered more than one [storage engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine) for saving data.

➥ *MVStore* is one of those storage engines, the latest, and the current default.

To quote the thorough [documentation page on MV_STORE](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html):

> **Storage Engine for H2**
>
> For H2 version 1.4 and newer, the MVStore is the default storage engine (supporting SQL, JDBC, transactions, MVCC, and so on). For older versions, append `;MV_STORE=TRUE` to the database URL.

Presumably, setting that flag to false engages the alternative storage engine.

### Choosing MVStore or not

As for why you might choose to use or avoid *MVStore*, I do not know the details. A search engine turned up [this old Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/dwAPTXO5xv0?pli=1) in 2015-08 by the name Thomas, so I wonder if this might be Thomas Mueller, the inventor of H2.

> Hi,
>
> The MVStore is relatively new and not yet as mature as the old storage mechanism (the PageStore). See also the documentation at http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html . Some advantages compared to the PageStore are: multi-version, simpler, more concurrent, writes less, optimized for SSDs. Disadvantage is that it temporarily needs more disk space, and is currently a bit slower.
>
> The PageStore is quite mature and will be supported in the future for some time. However, support will be phased out eventually.
>
> Regards,
>
> Thomas

I assume that now in 2020 versus 2015, and as the default for H2 version 1.4, the part about “new and not yet as mature” is no longer the case.

#### Multiversion concurrency control (MCC or MVCC)

From some quick searching and reading, it seems a major difference between the newer MVStore and the older PageStore is support for [multiversion concurrency control (MCC or MVCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

- MVCC support is a key feature of the newer MVStore, and is always enabled.
- MVCC support in the older PageStore was experimental, and eventually dropped.

See Issue pages:

- [*Always use MVCC with MVStore and never use it with PageStore #1204*](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1204) opened 2018-06.
- [*Remove useless MVCC / no MVCC conditions from MVStore code #1209*](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/1209)

---

By the way, using a [`javax.sql.DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation is generally recommended for getting connections rather than using `DriverManager` as seen in your sample code.

H2 provides the `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource` class as such an implementation. See [this documentation page](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html) for the list of options you can set.

```java
JdbcDataSource ds = new org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource();
ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:~/Database" );
ds.setUser( "scott" );
ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
return ds ;  // Return as the more general `javax.sql.DataSource` rather than H2-specific implementation.
```

Comment: What would be the alternative storage engine and in what circumstance would one set the MV_STORE to false?

Comment: @GPell7 I added another section to address your comment.